# $mul after $inc updates in MongoDB in one update

Tags: python, mongodb

Is it possible to update a single document by passing $inc and $mul operators in a single update document?

For example, I am trying to $mul after $inc in a given document using the following update document:

```
{
    "$inc": {"price": 100},
    "$mul": {"price": 10}
}
```

it raise WriteError: Cannot update 'shaped_high' and 'shaped_high' at the same time

Is there a way to do this or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple field operators ($inc, $mul, etc) in the same update operation. However, you cannot perform multiple modifications on the same field (of the document), in a single update operation.